# Ubuntu - /usr is full up, recommend anything in there I can delete?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, disk-space-utilization

A friend of mine partitioned his ubuntu system with /usr on a separate partition. That partition is now full. He can't use apt to install new software. Is there anything in /usr that he can safely delete (i.e. delete with `rm`, not `apt-get remove`)?

Since he can't install new software he can't install something like `dpigs` (the tool for checking which packages is taking up space)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried "sudo apt-get clean", "apt-get autoclean", and "apt-get autoremove"? If you use "man apt-get" that will describe what each does and may free some space.

Comment: clean only deletes stuff in /var.

Comment: As @womble said, clean only deletes things in /var. However autoremove will delete things in /usr, so it might save something

Comment: Whoops...didn't hurt to try it though :-) Looks like autoremove may give wanted results. It may have given some direction in which to look though.

Comment: On a similar quest, I found `sudo apt-get clean` to be most effective. `apt-get autoclean` and `apt-get autoremove` actually *decreased* available space. `clean` released it again. I checked disk space with `df -h`.

Comment: Running apt-get autoremove will remove lingering (older versions) linux-modules in the /usr directory (resulting in freeing up space).

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem.  First step was to find the top ten space hogs:

```
# cd /usr/share
# du -sm * | sort -rn | head -10
```

`/usr/share/doc` was 759MB on my system.  Space that could be useful for other purposes.  With *nix you can move things around without breaking things.  In my case I had plenty of free space on /home which was on a different partition:

```
# mkdir -p /home/share/doc
# mv /usr/share/doc/* /home/share/doc
# rmdir /usr/share/doc
# ln -s /home/share/doc /usr/share/doc
```

If you are really desparate, you can always mount an external hard drive and perform a similar relocation process.  The thing to watch for in that case is that you don't move anything critical to the system startup to the external drive.  `/usr/src` is another candidate, but I wouldn't move `/usr/lib`, too risky.

Answer (score 9):

```
/usr/share/doc
/usr/src
```

Comment: /usr/share/doc is the best place to purge.  /usr/src *can* contain locally-built stuff that can't be easily replaced.

Comment: yes, but sometimes it conain vanilla kernel and standard sources what easily can be restored from internet

Comment: /usr/share/doc is a good one to clean up, however, using apt-get to delete the files would be a better way. Is there some easy way to remove those files using apt?

Answer (score 1):

Another option not explored is to resize the partitions with the gparted livecd.
Backup your critical data first though and be prepared to loose the lot just in case.
I have done a resize a few times before and not had an issue so it's quite a robust procedure.

Another extension to this is that he could move everything from /usr to another larger partition linking it with a symbolic link to the new location.  Then using gparted you can remove the old /usr partition and merge /usr into the other partition.

Personally, I don't see the need to separate partitions for /usr /home etc like the old days.  It often results in more issues than it solves (i.e. running out of space).  Still, that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly hack would be to try uninstalling GNOME and get something lightweight instead. Presumably this shall save some space.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution by CyberFonic best, however when creating the symlink I had to give it the option for 'no dereference' since it's a directory.  Otherwise i would get errors when installing anything that tried to add a doc file, since /usr/share/doc wasn't being seen as a directory.  I couldn't cd to /usr/share/doc until I did the symlink like so:

`sudo ln -sfn /home/usr/share/doc /usr/share/doc`